# Warbler 1.3.2 not acknowledging Gemfile dependencies

Tags: ruby, jruby, warbler, jruby-rack

Its seems warbler is not using bundler to install dependent gems. I have had [this stack trace](https://gist.github.com/902d40aaefd0e69f41fb) appear on every gem that is a dependency and is auto specified in Gemfile.lock based [on my application's Gemfile](https://gist.github.com/199eed5060b5e66a2c62) . This is my [warble.rb](https://gist.github.com/5af7d07dc911a8be1a91)

Using
1. RubyGems 1.7.2 since 1.8.17 and others won't bundle bundler
2. JRuby 1.6.7 (for deployment)
3. Ruby-1.9.3-p125 (for local development)
4. Padrino 0.10.5
5. Warbler 1.3.2
6. rbenv
7. Mac OSX

Any idea why warbler won't include the dependent gems and I have to end up specifying each dependency explicitly in Gemfile (not Gemfile.lock).

Comment: weird, have you tried disabling the **gemjar** feature, same results ? also if you're warbling the Gemfile as is with MRI it seems to be asking for trouble since you're using gems that do not work on JRuby (and thus require-ing them when the .war boots might fail) e.g. *thin*, or *mysql2*